# How to make sure java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(String text, ParsePosition pos) method behavior in Android 7 is similar to the previous versions?

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, decimalformat

java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(String text, ParsePosition pos) is behaving differently in Android 7 compared to previous versions.

In Android 7, for the input string "123 45" (with space in between numbers), it returns the 'java.lang.Number' with value 12345 where as in pre-android7, it returns null.

I want to make sure the input "123 45" is an invalid input.  So, for my purpose, I want to always return null if the input is "123 45"(because a number shouldn't have spaces).  When I debugged in Android 7, the DecimalFormat class was inherently using android.icu.text but when I debugged in the previous versions, DecimalFormat class was using libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat.
The following page talks about migration from java.text.DecimalFormat to anroid.icu.text.DecimalFormat. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/icu4j-framework.html#migration

How do I make sure I am using libcore.icu.NaticeDecimalFormat in all devices?

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to use `libcore.icu.NativeDecimalFormat` in Android 7.0+. I would not assume that this class will continue to exist. Use a different validation approach (e.g., regex).

Comment: Since spaces are used as thousand separator in some languages (locales), the parser is simply being lenient. If you don't want to support thousand separators and locale-specific formatting, you should use something like `Integer.parseInt(String)` (or `Long` or `Double` variants) or `new BigDecimal(String)`.

Comment: Double.parseDouble was working for me but that doesn't have an overloaded method that takes Locale as a parameter(for my requirements, its essential to consider Locale)